# Git: Libraries hosted in a remote repository?

Tags: ios, git, github, bitbucket

I'm working in a project that has a few libraries that seem to be in a remote repository. For example:

[image: Remote library]

When I clone the project, all of the libraries with that icon are missing. Is there another command I need to execute to download them?

For reference, this is an iOS project and these are Objective C libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally third party libraries are added in project via CocoaPods or git submodules.

If your project using `CocoaPods` then you will find a `podfile` inside project directory, open terminal and navigate to directory contain podfile and then type in this command `pod install` to checkout all libraries,  it will create a workspace, once you have workspace open that project via workspace always.

If other libraries are added as submodule then you can checkout using `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: That was it. I used the "git submodule update --init" and it's downloading all the submodules. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept it as answer if it helped

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they are submodules of the repository you're clonning. Try adding the `--recursive` option to the clone command.